# Permission denied mounting NFS volume on raspberry PI with Synology

Tags: nfs, synology, raspbian

on my diskstation:

```
/volume1/Blockchain 192.168.1.27(rw,async,no_wdelay,insecure,no_root_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1025,anongid=100)
/volume1/BigStore   *(rw,async,no_wdelay,root_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1025,anongid=100)
```

On my raspberry pi /etc/fstab:

```
192.168.1.15:/volume1/Bitcoin /mnt/Bitcoin nfs rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,mountvers=3,mountport=892,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none
```

Running mount on the raspberry pi:

```
raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mount  192.168.1.15:/volume1/Bitcoin /mnt/Bitcoin
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.1.15:/volume1/Bitcoin
```

Any ideas

Comment: Isn't mounting a network drive to a computer related to managing information in a business.

Answer (score 2):

You expose/export two volumes:
/volume1/Blockchain
/volume1/BigStore

but you try to mount another one
/volume1/Bitcoin

so obviously you get access denied as it is not exposed/exported.